# PHP - file_put_contents() doesn't preserve filenames in output

Tags: php, file, compression, gzip

I would like to compress a .csv file on my server and put it into .gz (gzip) file using PHP.

I used `file_put_contents() like below:

```
$input = "test.csv";
$output = $input.".gz";

file_put_contents("compress.zlib://$output", file_get_contents($input));
```

However, when I open the gzip file (using winrar / 7zip), file extension is missing in the .gz archive; it's just "**test**" (without the file extension)?

It's not showing "**test.csv**" as I wanted. How to fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Does that mean the created file is just called "test"?

Comment: its not the created file, it was the file that i compress, when i open the gzip file using winrar / 7z, the test.csv doesn't have extension, it just "test" not "test.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no information on any "filename" inside that compressed file. You're simply compressing the raw binary data of the input file and are dumping it into an output file. The .gz file has no meta information on how many files are contained within it or what their names are. That's what the [TAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) file format is for, to provide that kind of meta information. You should make a tarball, then compress it using gz into a .tar.gz.

I'm not sure how to do this using PHP other than running a shell command through `exec`.
You may want to look at [ZIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) as an alternative with native PHP support.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this.,

```
$input = "test.txt";
exec("gzip ".$input);
```

It will work on linux server...

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure about what you're asking, but PHP already has a function for gzip compression, [gzencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php).

Use it like this

```
<?php
    $data = implode("", file("bigfile.txt"));
    $gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
    $fp = fopen("bigfile.txt.gz", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $gzdata);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english, i have to compress a .csv file using php, and i try and try many code, it can be create gzip file, but, inside the .gz file, only the "myFileName" not "myFileName.csv"

Comment: Try the code that I've posted. Replace `bigfile.txt` with your file `myFileName.csv`. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works properly on PHP 5.3.10 at least:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mats mats  8 Jul 17 13:05 test.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mats mats 31 Jul 17 13:05 test.csv.gz
```

You're not hiding file extensions for known file types in your explorer / navigator?

Comment: no, the file not hidden, when i open the gzip file it just show the "test" not "test.csv" on the .gz file.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the program you're using to open the gzipped file with. A gzipped file does not contain any information about file names, it's just convention to strip of the '.gz' part of the name and leave the rest intact (which is why archives are usually wrapped in a .tar file first, then gzipped).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$input = "test.csv";
$output = $input.".xml.gz";
```

I know it's ugly, but when using gzopen and gzwrite, I've found this to be the only way to preserve xml extension inside the archive. This way, when I extract it, I get the xml file.

Later on, once file is created, you can rename it in order to remove [.xml] thing before extension [.gz]